# KairosDB H2 vs Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0, kairosdb

I have an application where I need to load a lot of time series data to KairosDB then query it. I read on the [DB-Engines website](https://db-engines.com/en/system/KairosDB) that KairosDB is a distributed time series DBMS based on either Cassandra or H2.

I am curious as to what are the major differences between the H2 and Cassandra and when to use one over the other while working with KairosDB.

Answer (score 1):

H2 is a lightweight database often run in-memory and embedded in your application. It supports a subset of the SQL standard. Cassandra is a highly scaleable and always-on database for big data.  The choice comes down to the size and resiliency needs of your data.  Does your data fit in memory?  H2 might be a great choice.

Cassandra works well with time series data, you might find using Cassandra directly for time series works best.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK KairosDB included H2 support specifically for KairosDB development and shouldn't be used in production.

Also it looks like they're phasing out H2 support altogether